# HTML formatting in QML Text

Tags: html, qt, qml, qtquick2

I have a part of HTML code, which displays small table. In browser it looks like in the picture:
[image: HTML Table]

But when I want to display it in [Text QML](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qml-qtquick-text.html) (which, according to the documentation, should support HTML), I see:

[image: HTML table in QML]

(Orange rectangle is a part of rectangle, which is parent of `mytext`)

```
Text {
     id: mytext
     anchors.fill: parent
     text: "<div><table border='1'><caption><h4>Test stats</h4>"+
     "</caption><tr bgcolor='#9acd32'><th/><th>Number1</th><th>Number2</th></tr> <tr><th>Line1</th>"+
        "<td> 0 </td> <td> 1 </td> </tr> <tr><th>Line2</th> <td> 0 </td> <td> 1 </td> </tr>"+
        "<tr><th>Line3</th> <td> 0 </td> <td> 0 </td> </tr> <tr><th>Line4</th> <td> 1 </td> <td> 0 </td> </tr>"+
        "<tr><th>Line5</th> <td> 1 </td> <td> 1 </td> </tr> <tr><th>Line6</th> <td> 1 </td> <td> 1 </td> </tr> </div>"
}
```

So how to display correctly this HTML table in QML (QtQuick 2.0)? Is it possible without using WebView?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Add [`textFormat: Text.RichText`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-text.html#textFormat-prop):

```
Text {
     id: mytext
     anchors.fill: parent
     textFormat: Text.RichText
     text: "<div><table border='1'><caption><h4>Test stats</h4>"+
     "</caption><tr bgcolor='#9acd32'><th/><th>Number1</th><th>Number2</th></tr> <tr><th>Line1</th>"+
        "<td> 0 </td> <td> 1 </td> </tr> <tr><th>Line2</th> <td> 0 </td> <td> 1 </td> </tr>"+
        "<tr><th>Line3</th> <td> 0 </td> <td> 0 </td> </tr> <tr><th>Line4</th> <td> 1 </td> <td> 0 </td> </tr>"+
        "<tr><th>Line5</th> <td> 1 </td> <td> 1 </td> </tr> <tr><th>Line6</th> <td> 1 </td> <td> 1 </td> </tr> </div>"
}
```