# Why does Qt::mightBeRichText() not detact HTML table tags as rich text?

Tags: html, text, qml, richtext

I'm using a HTML table within a QML Text component. My problem is that `textFormat: Text.AutoText` does not automatically recognize my HTML table as a rich text ([QML Text documentary](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-text.html#textFormat-prop)).

Searching for a solution I found [HTML formatting in QML Text](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26333867/5134351) which is quite close to my problem. 
The solution given: just setting `textFormat: Text.RichText` I knew before. But I can not use it as setting the `textFormat: Text.RichText` also changes how the `contentWidth` of the QML Text component behaves.

```
Text {
  id: myPlainText
  width: 500
  wrapMode: Text.Wrap
  text: "Hallo stackoverflow.com"

  textFormat: Text.AutoText
}

Text {
  id: myRichText
  width: 500
  wrapMode: Text.Wrap
  text: "Hallo stackoverflow.com"      

  textFormat: Text.RichText
}
```

Accessing `myPlainText.contentWidth` will give me the actual used with of the text even if it is shorter than 500.
Accessing `myRichText.contentWidth` does always give me 500.
For me the information of the actual used with, which is `contentWidth` when no `RichText` is involved, is important for layout reasons, as this is what my component is mostly used for. Hitting the with limit (eg. 500) for HTML tables would be ok, even so I would prefer knowing the actual table with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [Documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-text.html#textFormat-prop)

> If the text format is Text.AutoText the Text item will automatically determine whether the text should be treated as **styled text**. This determination is made using Qt::mightBeRichText() which uses a fast and therefore simple heuristic. It mainly checks whether there is something that looks like a tag before the first line break. Although the result may be correct for common cases, there is no guarantee.

As you can see, it distiguishes between **plain** and **styled** text.
The third category: **RichText** is not supported by **AutoText**.

This means for **AutoText** you need to resort to the reduced set of tags, seen in the documentation:

```
<b></b> - bold
<strong></strong> - bold
<i></i> - italic
<br> - new line
<p> - paragraph
<u> - underlined text
<font color="color_name" size="1-7"></font>
<h1> to <h6> - headers
<a href=""> - anchor
<img src="" align="top,middle,bottom" width="" height=""> - inline images
<ol type="">, <ul type=""> and <li> - ordered and unordered lists
<pre></pre> - preformatted
&gt; &lt; &amp;
```

If you need the width of your text, try to use

```
myRichText.implicitWidth
```

This will give you the width of the text, if it is not wrapped.
Propbably, due to the advanced posibilities, it always works with a maximum `contentWidth`. Therefore it is not possible to use e.g. `elide` together with `RichText`. The unexpected behavior of `contentWidth` however seems like a bug to me - in either the source or more likely in the documentation.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that `Qt::mightBeRichText()` does actually check "mightBeStyledText"

Comment: Again tank you for the hint to `myRichText.implicitWidth`. In combination with `Math.min(myRichText.implicitWidth, myRichText.contentWidth)` this seams to give me the with I was searching for

Comment: Not exactly: Consider this: `Text { text: 'This is so Supercalifragilisticexpialidocious'; width: 200; wrapMode: Text.WordWrap; font.pixelSize: 11 }` For me this has a contentWidth of 160, a implicitWidth of 208 and a width of 200, so for `textFormat: Text.RichText` the measurement would be 40px off. Still, it is most likely the best measurement you can get unless you are going to calculate it for your self, letter by letter.